# A table is automatically generated on db creation in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

whenever i create a new database in postgresql, a table named 'users' automatically gets created. I do not need this table and I wonder where is the setting that I should set to prevent this behavior.

Comment: Someone has added `users` to your server's `template1` database; details here: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/manage-ag-templatedbs.html

Comment: The question was a little broadish, a little more verbosity was needed according to my taste.